# Why doesn't my welcome message in discord.js work?

Tags: discord.js

i have tried a lot of different ways but this seemed the most used and successful! But it doesn't seem to work for me? I don't need an embed just a simple message. How do i do this correctly?

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async newMember => {
    const welcomeChannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'my channel id is here')
    welcomeChannel.send('welcome we hope you have fun')
  })
```

Comment: Do you have the `GuildMembers` intent enabled?

Comment: huh? how do i check this?

Comment: Just go to the place where you declare the client and paste that code here

Answer (score -2):

I've tried your code on myself, it is working exactly just as you intended, so I'm assuming that you might not have put the correct intent. Now discord bot need specific intent (depends on what you are trying to do) to work correctly .

And in your case, you are probably missing the "GUILD_MEMBERS" intent. Change it like:

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: 'GUILD_MEMBERS',
})
```

Also, in case if you are building a local bot and you don't care about intent or you just simply got annoyed by it.
You can also use

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: 32767,
})
```